# Create a CSV file of all the addresses in an area from OSM file

Tags: csv, openstreetmap

I am interested in creating a CSV file of addresses from the area below (in the format **street name, town, postcode, city, latitude, longitude**).

[image]

**This is what I've done so far:**

1) Download osm files for the UK at http://nick.dev.openstreetmap.org/downloads/planet/

2) Run osmfilter:

```
osmfilter uk.osm --keep="highway=residential =primary =secondary =tertiaty =unclassified" >uk_streets.osm
```

3) Run osmconvert:

```
osmconvert uk_streets.osm --csv="@lon @lat addr:city addr:street" --csv-headline --csv-separator=, -o=uk_streets.csv
```

**My problems**

- I can't figure out how to only pull addresses from the Milton Keynes
  area, the above script seems to pull from the whole of UK (i.e. not in
  the bounds shown in the image above).
- There were lots of gaps in the data after running the script, I could
  not find some of the addresses that appeared on the OSM website in
  the database

**Question**

- How would I refactor my osmfilter and osmconvert
  commands to pull the necessary information for the Milton Keynes
  area ONLY?

Comment: Can you name some examples of addresses missing in your result but existing in the OSM database? And consider asking your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org or http://gis.stackexchange.com instead, people here tend to close questions way too fast.

Comment: Oh, you already asked there. Here's the link for other people running into the same problem: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/35148/create-a-csv-file-of-all-the-addresses-in-milton-keynes-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clip the data to only the area you're interested in again with osmconvert, you can create a poly file (with Josm or other program - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format), then using this to clip the file, see this section
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Clipping_based_on_a_Polygon

Answer (score 3):

Another technique is to use https://openaddresses.io/

Does not use OSM data, but gives you a similar (better?) result.